# R - count number of list components

Tags: r

I know that in R, you can index through a list with double brackets, i.e. `mylist[[1]]`. How do you count the number of elements in that list (not the number of elements in each list item, but the maximum `n` in `mylist[[n]]`)? I tried `NROW`, `NCOL`, `dim`, among others.

Some example code for the desired behavior of some function `num.items(list)`:

```
require(testthat)
mylist <- list(array(rnorm(4),dim=c(2,2)),array(rnorm(4),dim=c(2,2)))

expect_that( num.items(mylist), equals(2) )
```

Comment: What happened when you tried `length(mylist)`?

Comment: Ah, geez, I had myself confused with a couple variables in my code. You're right, length is the right choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`length`?

```
> length(mylist)
[1] 2
```